# Why do I get a Lightbox MVC razor error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, lightbox

I'm trying to display an image using Lightbox with the logic something like this:

```
public ActionResult displayImg()

    string lbx = "<a href=\"~/Content/Images/lighthouse.jpg\" rel=\"lightbox\"></a>";
   return View (lbx);
```

But it gives an error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Illegal characters in path. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Comment: That code makes no sense whatsoever.  It also has nothing to do with Razor.

Comment: @user1112006 - if you want to show an image on the page, render an `<img>` tag. Also you can't use the `~` syntax in text you send to the browser - it needs to be replaced server side.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `<a ...></a>` as a *view name*, which is translated into a filename in your project.
That's not a valid filename.

You probably want to return `Content(...)`, which returns a literal string.
You also need to map the path using the URL class.

Comment: Thanks. I have all the scripts for lightbox jquery in .cshtml and when changing to return Content(lbx) the page just went blank. Also with <a..>abc</a> it needs another click on 'abc'. How can we just display the image without any click? Can you provide in code details? Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense.  You need to figure out what you want to do and write code that does it.